# How to add a space between two paragraphs within the column text?

Tags: line-breaking, reledmac, reledpar, vskip

I am trying to add spaces between paragraphs when I start a new section of my document. \vskip and \bigbreak didn't add empty lines inside Parcolumns. Is there a proper way of doing this?

I am using this Overleaf [template][1].

I finally worked out the right way of doing this, helped by @maïeul, the maintainer of (r)(e)ledmac/(r)(e)ledpar LaTeX packages. The compilation problem happened because I needed to have a mirror of the left column on the right, with matching sections on both sides. For instance, when I added a new left section, I forgot to add a corresponding right section so LateX could compile the document correctly.

I have updated the FULL MWE below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{palatino,url}
\usepackage[portuguese,english]{babel}
\tolerance=5000\relax%

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My name}
\rhead{page \thepage}
\cfoot{some text}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\date{(taken from the reledmac documentation)}
\title{Setting Parallel Texts with reledpar}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This file provides two minimal examples of typesetting parallel texts with reledmac plus reledpar. 

The first minimal example is parallel typesetting in columns, the second one is parallel typesetting in pages.
\end{abstract}


\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{First Left Section title}]
Other left side paragraph. Other left side paragraph.

Other left side paragraph. Other left side paragraph.
\pend 
\pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Second Left Section title}]
Other left side paragraph. Other left side paragraph.

Other left side paragraph. Other left side paragraph
            \pend
            \pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Third Left Section title}]
Other left side paragraph. Other left side paragraph.

Other left side paragraph. Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
             \pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Fourth Left Section title}]
Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph. Other left side paragraph.
\pend 
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
             \pend
            \pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{First Right Section title}]
Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.

Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
\pend
\pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Second Right Section title}]
Other right side paragraph.  Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
             \pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Third Right Section title}]
Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.

Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
             \pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Fourth Right Section title}]
Other right side paragraph.  Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
\pend 
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pairs} 
\Columns



\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: this is a hack, really.  before the lines where you want a gap, add a line `\strut\par`.  that will leave an actual (empty) line, which will, unfortunately, be counted and numbered.

Comment: Thanks, @barbarabeeton. That did the trick! I had to add \strut\par \strut\par (two times) in order to get the space before the previous paragraph.

Comment: *"Overleaf [template][1]"* -> The link is missing.

Answer (score 1):

1. To insert section between paragraph in parallel typesetting, you must use optional argument of \pstart. That will made the section title being parallel.
2. To insert verticle space before that section title, you must add it also in the optional argument of pstart.

So

`\pstart[\vskip2\baselineskip\section{My section title}]`

All is explained
1. In § 5.2.3 of reledmac handbook
2. In § 16 of reledmac handbook
3. In exampled provided with reledmac documentation

Full MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{palatino,url}
\usepackage[portuguese,english]{babel}
\tolerance=5000\relax%

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My name}
\rhead{page \thepage}
\cfoot{some text}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\date{(taken from the reledmac documentation)}
\title{Setting Parallel Texts with reledpar}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This file provides two minimal examples of typesetting parallel texts with reledmac plus reledpar. 

The first minimal example is parallel typesetting in columns, the second one is parallel typesetting in pages.
\end{abstract}


\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Section title}]
Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Section title}]
Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.            
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pairs} 
\Columns

%\begin{pages}
 %   \begin{Leftside}
  %      \beginnumbering
%            \pstart
         %       Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
 %           \pend
  %          \pstart
          %      Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
 %           \pend
   %     \endnumbering
 %   \end{Leftside}
 %   \begin{Rightside}
 %       \beginnumbering
  %          \pstart
   %             Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
    %        \pend
      %      \pstart
   %             Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
       %     \pend
     %   \endnumbering
 %   \end{Rightside}

%\end{pages} 
%\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this @maïeul. I'll look into the reledmac documentation later. Using your example into my document resulted in a compilation error. So far, inserting \strut\par to add empty lines before and/or a paragraph has proved to be a good workaround solution.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in my code. corrected now.

Comment: I have complted with a FULL MWE. YOu should not use the workaround with \strut, which will create problem in some specific case.

Comment: Thank you you so muck for this explanation. I'm sure i'll be able to use it.

I don't want to create numbered sections. All I want is to give headings to some sections of text and add more of the same within one pair, e.g.

Comment: \strut\par
\strut\par
\textbf{Heading}
Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.

Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.

Comment: \strut\par
\strut\par
\textbf{Heading 2}
Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.

Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.

Comment: I managed to compile a 72 page document using this workaround and it looks perfect to me.

Comment: I tried to replace \textbf{Heading} with 
\pstart[\vskip\baselineskip\section{Heading}] in my document, but I got an compilation error. It's probably because that's not how it's supposed to be done.

Comment: if you explain explictily your compilation error, I could help you. But I can ensure you that your workaround could have side effect that you can't imagine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79224/discussion-between-maieul-and-claud).